# Appending to empty lists in list to transpose a matrix, only last value remains

Tags: python, append

Here is problem:

```
spam=[[1,2,3,'a'],
      [4,5,6,'b'],
      [7,8,9,'c']]
for j in range(len(spam)):
    for i in range(len(spam[0])):
        bacon0=[[] for n in range(len(spam[0]))]
        bacon0[i].append(spam[j][i])
```

I'm expecting output to be like:

```
bacon0=[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],['a','b','c']]
```

but I'm getting:

```
bacon0=[[],[],[],['c']]
```

I want to transpose matrix but without using `numpy` or `zip()`.

Comment: You *re*initialize `bacon0` each time in the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I missed that, works perfect now.

Comment: You can transpose with `zip`: `list(list(x) for x in zip(*spam))`.

Comment: Why no `zip` .. ?

Comment: Because I'm new in python and I'm not there yet. I read about it but still don't want to use it, basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recreate `bacon0` each iteration of your inner loop:

```
for j in range(len(spam)):
    for i in range(len(spam[0])):
        bacon0=[[] for n in range(len(spam[0]))]
```

That replaces the previous versions each time. Move it *out* and *before* the loops:

```
bacon0 = [[] for n in range(len(spam[0]))]
for j in range(len(spam)):
    for i in range(len(spam[0])):
```

Demo:

```
>>> spam=[[1,2,3,'a'],
...       [4,5,6,'b'],
...       [7,8,9,'c']]
>>> bacon0 = [[] for n in range(len(spam[0]))]
>>> for j in range(len(spam)):
...     for i in range(len(spam[0])):
...         bacon0[i].append(spam[j][i])
...
>>> bacon0
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

`zip()` would make this a lot more straightforward, but if you really don't want to use it, at least look at using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and direct iteration to access your values:

```
bacon0 = [[] for _ in range(len(spam[0]))]
for row in spam:
    for i, value in enumerate(row):
        bacon0[i].append(value)
```